# Scroll Textview inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/activityRecicler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:stackFromEnd="true"
            />
```

And I have a row layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/description"/>

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/solutions"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

And the wrap content work, but my problem is that `TextView` with id description It could be very long and so, I would have a Scroll for this TextView.
How could I do this?

Comment: wrap it inside scrollview?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the problem. The recycler scrolls and it displays whole item, right? So what are you trying to achieve? TextViews are multiline so by simple Recycler scrolling you will see whole content.

Comment: Can you post the screen shot of the screen you are currently getting. SS with a long text is preferred.

Comment: thankyou i posted!

Comment: well you don't need to handle scroll of textview inside the recycler view that is automatically taken care of.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change your layout XML to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/solutions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And then in your activity:

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        findViewById(R.id.scroll_view).getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        return false;
    }
});
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: hello! thanks, activityRecicler is RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.activityRecicler); 
But Chldscroll?

Comment: in xml file give above.

Comment: yes, but How  can I have access from activity to rowLayout in activity?

Comment: I put ChildScroll in my View holder, but my problem persist, if i try touch in horizontal it scroll a bit, but nothing if I touch in vertical

Comment: finally I'have resolved!!! I have put

`solutions.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;
                }
            });`

In my View Holder...

Comment: Hi! You don't really have to call `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()` for `activityRecicler`, in fact, there was no need to call `onTouch(,)` in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: For me it was sufficient to just set
`childScroll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }
});`

Answer (score 13):

I am beginner on Android and so I don't know if my solution it's good.
I have put in **Layout Row** as suggested by @Payal

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/childScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/solutions"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="long_text"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
    </ScrollView>
```

And in My **ViewHolder**

```
public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            solutions = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.solutions);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            scrollable = (ScrollView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.childScroll);


            solutions.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;
                }
            });

//Enabling scrolling on TextView.

            solutions.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        }
```

And it's work.
I can scroll the TextView in my RecyclerView

Comment: If some answer helped you, what you should do is upvote that answer and mark it as correct. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: And please don't post comments as an answer.

Comment: Hello Surfian, sorry for comment.
this answer it is mine and i can accept my answer in the next 21 hours

Comment: I see that you've modified the code provided by @PayalSorathiya to fit into your scenario, but it's his solution and I guess it's fair to mark his answer as correct. Marking his answer will award him points and to you as well. More information will be in the link I posted above.

Comment: Perfect answer , none of the code work except this.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code on your textview id in viewholder.

```
 scrollable = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
//Enabling scrolling on TextView.
 scrollable.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

add in `TextView`**layout**

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a new class

```
public class AutoScrollingTextView extends TextView {

    public AutoScrollingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public AutoScrollingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AutoScrollingTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect     previouslyFocusedRect) {
        if (focused) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focused) {
        if (focused) {
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(focused);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFocused() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then in xml

```
<AutoScrollingTextView
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"/>
```

This works !!!

Answer (score 0):

either you can wrap it in `scrollview` like this

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_height="100px" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"> 
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text_view" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:text="long_text"/>
</ScrollView>
```

or

add these two attributes to yout `textview`

```
android:maxLines="5"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

and add below line in your code

```
textview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: change your `textview`'s `width` to `fill_parent` instead of `wrap_content`

Comment: Done but the problem is strange, I can see  the scrollbar but scroll if I touch in horizontal on  textView and not always! :/ I don't understand what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

rowlayout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:lines="1"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#ff4500" />
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/solutions"/>
</LenearLayout>
```

and in activity

```
descrptionTextview.setSelected(true);
```